# How can you devolve a data frame into seperate data frames based on strings in the data frames column?

Tags: r

I have a combined parts list data frame that has parts list information for Mechanical supplies and Electrical supplies. I would like to separate the  Mechanical supplies and Electrical supplies into their own data frames based off of certain descriptors in one of the PL.Combined columns.

For Example I have:

```
PL.Combined

PART.NUMBER     DESCRIPTION
    1x              NUT 
    2x              WIRE
    3x              BOLT
    4x              CIRCUIT
    5x              BRACKET
    6X              CONTACT
```

I would like to extract the Mechanical parts {NUT, BOLT, BRACKET} from the Electrical parts {WIRE, CIRCUIT, CONTACT}.

To have something like:

```
>PL.Electrical

PART.NUMBER     DESCRIPTION 
    2x              WIRE
    4x              CIRCUIT
    6X              CONTACT

>PL.Mechanical

PART.NUMBER     DESCRIPTION
    1x              NUT 
    3x              BOLT
    5x              BRACKET
```

Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: use subset() function ? Or if you want to simplify the filtering bit, data.table is good and fast - https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, I am looking into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a specified inventory list, you could use that to split your data into 2 `data.frames`. A nice way to handle this could be done as follows:

```
inventory<-read.csv("stackoverflow.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
inventory
  PART.NUMBER           DESCRIPTION
1          1x          1/2 inch NUT
2          2x              2mm WIRE
3          3x            screw BOLT
4          4x closed & open CIRCUIT
5          5x         joint BRACKET
6          6X      adhesive CONTACT

inventory$New_desc<-do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(inventory[,2],split=" "), function(x) tail(x,1)))

inventory

  PART.NUMBER           DESCRIPTION New_desc
1          1x          1/2 inch NUT      NUT
2          2x              2mm WIRE     WIRE
3          3x            screw BOLT     BOLT
4          4x closed & open CIRCUIT  CIRCUIT
5          5x         joint BRACKET  BRACKET
6          6X      adhesive CONTACT  CONTACT

Mech<-c("NUT", "BOLT", "BRACKET")
Elec<-c("WIRE", "CIRCUIT", "CONTACT")

Split_inventory<-list()
Split_inventory[['Mech']]<-inventory[which(inventory$New_desc %in% Mech),]
Split_inventory[['Elec']]<-inventory[which(inventory$New_desc %in% Elec),]
```

If you not too familiar with `lists`, splitting them into `data.frames` follow the same logic:

```
Mech_inventory<-inventory[which(inventory$New_desc%in% Mech),]
Elec_inventory<-inventory[which(inventory$New_desc%in% Elec),]
```

Comment: Quick question, will that recognize the string pattern and remove all rows  that contain that pattern or will it only match to that exact description word. For example I would need to be able to identify "1/2 INCH BOLT" and not just "BOLT". If that makes sense. Thank you for your answer. I am currently testing out a couple of different approaches and will try this one as well. I will update you with how it works for my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately this will identify only EXACT matches. If you use `regex` with `grep` and/or `gsub` in a clever way, I am sure you could get this to work with your data if string matching might be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. I am currently using something like  mech.pattern="NUT|BOLT|BRACKET"  in  PL.Reduce <- PL.Combined[!grepl(pattern,PL.Combined$DESCRIPTION),] to delete Mechanical parts descriptions from PL.Combined. That requires the creation of a mechanical descriptions pattern set. Is there a way to take all PL.Combined$DESCRIPTION column strings and create a col that contains only single word descriptions that can be used to create a master mech pattern set. So basically just break up multi-word descriptions into single words that can be used in the mech.pattern.

Comment: Just to let you know, I am currently only worried about reducing PL.Combined into a master Electrical Parts list. I can go back later and use the mech.pattern to create the master Mechanical Parts list if need be.

Comment: See my edit. Obviously the solution to your problem will depend on the nature of your descriptions. I have added a solution which grabs the last word of the description and creates  a new column on which can be used to desperate your inventory

Comment: I see, thank you. That is a nice solution. The data I am working with is not as "nice" as in your example but it does lead me in the right direction. Thank you for your examples.